# Matlab sound with a function for a keyboard

Tags: matlab

I have to declare this function where phi is a random value from 0 to 2pi

$$x(n)=A \cos (2 \pi f n T+\phi)$$

Have to declare it like this and use it with sound

createWaveform(frequency,fs,duration,A)

Now I've done this

```
createWaveform(440,8000,2,1);


function createWaveform(frequency,fs,duration,A)
    n = linspace(0,duration-1/fs,duration*fs);
    for i=  1:duration
        sound(A*cos(2*pi*frequency*n(i)+(2*pi).*rand(1,1)));
    end
end



    function [tone] = note(keynum,relDuration,fullDuration,fs)
                basetone = 440;
                frequency = basetone * nthroot(2,12)^(keynum-49);
                [tone]=createWaveform(frequency,fs,relDuration*fullDuration,1);
    end
```

So done that the sounds are still weird and no real tones they are like knocking on a broken microphone

Comment: i guess that's my next task where it is stated that I have to define this function [tone] = note(keynum,relDuration,fullDuration,fs)  where relDuration should be my note length and full duration the duration forr a whole note in seconds but I have no clue how to implement that

Comment: well nvm literally a function to generate a note tone

Comment: Have to use a ADSR Curve later on

Comment: Again, `createWaveform` outputs a single value, that's not a waveform. It must output an array of numbers. You need to define an array `n` with all the time points at which to compute the wave form, then generate the output at each of those values of `n`. `duration` is not one of the variables in the equation you're expected to implement. It is the largest value of `n`. `n` should run from `0` to `duration` in steps given by the sampling frequency `fs`.

Comment: Thanks. So n should contain duration/fs values?  starts at 0 add 1/fs vor the next and so on?

Comment: Yes. Or rather `duration*fs` values. `n = linspace(0,duration-1/fs,duration*fs)`.

Comment: I'll close this question as a dupe of your newer one, since the newer one will attract more attention. But please don't post duplicate questions. The right way to attract attention to your question is to write a good question. I suggest you read [ask] and the links given there for tips on how to do so.