# Matlab creating piano sounds (strange sound problem)

Tags: matlab

Hello I have to build a program that is able to play some piano sounds from beethoven elise

Now I have implemented the function for the frequency and the sound but it sounds strange and not at all like piano notes.

Could someone give me advice on how to fix this?

```
createWaveform(440,8000,2,1);


    function [sinusoid] = createWaveform(frequency,fs,duration,A)
     n = linspace(0,duration-1/fs,duration*fs);
     sinusoid = 1:duration*fs;
     for i = 1:duration*fs
      sinusoid(i) = A*cos(2*pi*frequency*n(i)*(1/fs)+(2*pi).*rand(1,1));
     end
    end


 end
```

Here is the part where I am attempting to build tones to the right piano note

```
%function [tone] = note(keynum,relDuration,fullDuration,fs)
   %basetone = 440;
   % frequency = basetone * nthroot(2,12)^(keynum-49);
  %[tone]=createWaveform(frequency,fs,relDuration*fullDuration,1);
%end
```

Edit: I've deleted all my old code and wrote the following that did the job

```
   %sound(createWaveform(1000,8000,1,1));
   sound(note(24,1/2,1,8000));



   function [sinusoid] = createWaveform(frequency,fs,duration,A)
    Fs = fs;                   % samples per second
    dt = 1/Fs;                   % seconds per sample           % seconds
    t = (0:dt:duration)';     % seconds
    %%Sine wave:
    Fc = frequency;                     % hertz
    sinusoid = A.*cos(2*pi*Fc*t+(2*pi).*rand(1,1));
   % Plot the signal versus time:
   end

   function [tone] = note(keynum,relDuration,fullDuration,fs)
             basetone = 440;
             frequency = basetone * nthroot(2,12)^(keynum-49);
             tone=createWaveform(frequency,fs,relDuration*fullDuration,0.5);
   end

   function [E] = envel(relDuration,fullDuration,fs)
   param = 0;
   for i = 0:fs:relDuration*fullDuration
    E(i)=relDuration*fullDuration;
    i=i+1;
   end

   end
```

Comment: Well, clearly because piano notes are muuuuuuch more complex than a single frequency cos wave. There are secondary frequencies, inharmonities and much more other things going on.

Comment: So any suggestions? My exercise is to build a function that generates notes with the function I've used..

Comment: So you did not write the function? In any case, it won't sound like a piano, it will sound like a pitch, more like a very bad version of a piano, but may do the job for your exercise.

Comment: actually it sounds like someone's knocking or if i change the linspace like a broken speaker..

Comment: Note that `A*cos(2*pi*frequency*n(i)+(2*pi).*rand(1,1))` is a single value, [as I've explained earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59911805/7328782). Calling `sound` with a single value is going to produce some weird noise. You need to call `sound` with the whole signal (your "waveform"). `createWaveform` must output an array of the same size as `n`, and this array should be the input too `sound`.

Comment: And how excactly can I do that? I've tried it in the edit I've made

Comment: actually I am getting heavy noise

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Comments, the sound that a piano makes is quite complicated. As such this is not a Matlab challenge, just a math problem.

Now that you know this, you 'just' need to come up with a reasonable mathematical approximation, and from here it should be straight forward to implement in Matlab.

Here is something to get you started with the math:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/mathematical-equation-for-the-sound-wave-that-a-piano-makes